# function doesn't return an object with an appropriate generic class R

Tags: r

I'm running a slight variation of the example contained in the help of the function `timeseriesWF` but using a user defined function (`svmR`) instead of `svm`. However I get `Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"` but don't understand why the example works with `svm`but doesn't with `svmR`:

```
library(DMwR)
library(e1071)
getSymbols('^GSPC',from='2008-01-01',to='2012-12-31')
data.model <- specifyModel(
  Next(100*Delt(Ad(GSPC))) ~ Delt(Ad(GSPC),k=1:10)+Delt(Vo(GSPC),k=1:3))
data <- as.data.frame(modelData(data.model))
colnames(data)[1] <- 'PercVarClose'

svmR <- function(form,train,test,b.t=0.1,s.t=-0.1,...) {
  require(e1071)
  t <- svm(form,train,...)
  p <- predict(t,test)
}

spExp <- experimentalComparison(
  c(dataset(PercVarClose ~ .,data,'SP500_2008_2012')),
  variants('timeseriesWF',
           learner='svmR',learner.pars=list(cost=10),
           type=c('slide','grow'),relearn.step=200,
           evaluator.pars=list(stats='nmse')),
  mcSettings(2,0.5,0.25))
```

EDIT: linux and windows run different versions of the package.

Comment: Without installing the packages, I guess `svm` returns an object of class "svm", which `experimentalComparison` knows how to handle (apparently by calling `predict`, which will use the `predict.svm` method). Your function doesn't return an object of the appropriate class.

Comment: @Roland thanks for your answer. Do you know how can I change the function so it returns `double` class? I'm confused because the data passed to svm is a `dataframe`.

Comment: Obviously you haven't understood my comment. Reread it.

Comment: @Roland I see that if pass an argument of class `svm` it works however I would like to generalice as much as possible so I can use other type of learners as well with the same function. In fact if I use `nnet` then it works as well but not with my function so could you help me to get the return of an approapriate generic class?